# Make R invoke NextMethod when possible

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to make R to invoke NextMethod when there is a next-class:

```
e = new.env()
class(e) = c(class(e), "c11", "c22")
print.c11 = function(e, ...) {
    print(e$x); 
    tryCatch({
        NextMethod()
    }, warning = function(w) {
    }, error = function(e) {
    }, finally = {
    })
}
print.c22 = function(e, ...) {
    print(e$y)
    tryCatch({
        NextMethod()
    }, warning = function(w) {
    }, error = function(e) {
    }, finally = {
    })
}
e$x = 111
e$y = 222
print(e)
```

This is a dirty hack which will cover all errors and warnings that the method might produce. How can this be done properly?

---

The above code kind of works without the tryCatch block, that's because, I think, the print.default function was invoked. Now take an example (modified) out of Hadley's advanced R book:

```
> baz <- function(x) UseMethod("baz", x)
> baz.c <- function(x) c("c", NextMethod())
> baz.d <- function(x) c("d", NextMethod())
> c <- structure(1, class = c("c", "d"))
> baz(c)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in NextMethod() : no method to invoke
```

Ideally the NextMethod function should return NULL if there is no next class.

Comment: What is the expected output here ?  Not that you get the same thing if you remove all the try catch statement.

Comment: If I remove the tryCatch in print.c22, I will get an error.

Comment: I don't get an error message with `print.c11 = function(e) { print(e$x); NextMethod() }; print.c22 = function(e) { print(e$y); NextMethod() }`. Also, is your inheritance vector as intended -- 'environment' extends class 'c11'? Or did you mean for 'c11' to extend (specialize) 'environment', `c("c11", class(e))`? And the signature for 'print' methods should follow the generic, `print.c22 = function(x, ...) ...`.

Comment: I want to append "c11" and "c22" to class(e) because I want to make sure environment methods still work as usual. See my edits.

Answer (score 5):

Implement a default method, e.g.,

```
baz.default <- function(x) NULL
```

and

```
> c <- structure(1, class = c("c", "d"))
> baz(c)
[1] "c" "d"
```